# How do i fix this error even though there is no red text

Tags: java, user-interface

Right now i'm making a GUI and i'm getting this error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:594)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:679)
    at GUI.main(GUI.java:13)
```

here is my base code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI {

    private Container mainPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loot and Scoot");
        frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainPanel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,700));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}
```

I've tried fixing this problem with Alt+Enter but nothing is wrong there is no red text

Comment: `mainPanel` is null.... "nothing is wrong there is no red text" - that's just the IDE letting you know if there is anything "obviously wrong".

Comment: `frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainPanel);` This line creates a new `GUI` object, then passes that object's `mainPanel` member variable to the function `setContentPane()`. However, at no point do you ever create `mainPanel` so it retains its initial value of `null`.

Comment: Note that (probably) there is no "red text" since this is a run time error and not a syntax error.

Comment: how do i create a mainpanel

Comment: I suggest you find a good book or tutorial on creating a UI with Swing: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+tutorial

Comment: @HunterLindsey, `mainPanel = new JPanel();`

Comment: thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a

```
mainPanel = new JPanel
```

i've edited my code correctly so it works now, here it is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI {

    private static Container mainPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loot and Scoot");
        frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainPanel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,700));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel{
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loot and Scoot");
        frame.setContentPane(new GUI());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,700));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}
```